# Custom Dialog with Checkbox in the Title

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to create a Custom dialog via DialogFragment.
i want to have a Title and a Checkbox.

I am doing this by using a Custom Title as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:text="Categories"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/all"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="All"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now i want to reference this this Check box and add a listener to the Checkbox.

I want to achieve something like this

[image]

What i have tried ?

```
public class CategoriesDialogFragment extends SherlockDialogFragment {

    ListView dialog_ListView;
    static CheckBox chk_all;
    static SelectViewHolder viewHolder;

    private static ArrayAdapter<mItems> listAdapter;
    static ArrayList<String> checked = new ArrayList<String>();

    protected static CharSequence[] _categories = { "Amusement Park",
            "Bird Sanctuary", "Wild Life", "River", "Hill Station", "Temple",
            "Rafting", "Fishing", "Hiking", "Museums" };

    protected static boolean[] _selections = new boolean[_categories.length];
    PlacesListAdapter adapter;
    ListView listView;
    Button dialog_ok;

    static int TAG = 0;
    static mItems categories;

    static mItems orig;

    public static CategoriesDialogFragment newInstance(int title) {
        CategoriesDialogFragment frag = new CategoriesDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("title", title);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.context);
        //dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setTitle("Categories");
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        dialog_ok = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_category_ok);

        dialog_ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog_ListView = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.listViewDialog);

        dialog_ListView
                .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View item,
                            int position, long id) {
                        categories = listAdapter.getItem(position);

                        orig = listAdapter.getItem(position);

                        categories.toggleChecked();

                        viewHolder = (SelectViewHolder) item.getTag();
                        viewHolder.getCheckBox().setChecked(
                                categories.isChecked());

                        if (!viewHolder.getCheckBox().isChecked()) {
                            TAG = 1;
                            chk_all.setChecked(false);

                        }
                        TAG = 0;

                        /*
                         * if (viewHolder.getCheckBox().isChecked()) {
                         * 
                         * TAG = 0; }
                         */

                        for (int i = 0; i < _categories.length; i++) {
                            categories = listAdapter.getItem(i);
                            if (!categories.isChecked()) {
                                break;
                            }

                            if (i == _categories.length - 1) {
                                TAG = 1;
                                chk_all.setChecked(true);
                                TAG = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

        chk_all = (CheckBox) dialog.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxAll);
        chk_all.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                if (TAG != 1) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                            categories = listAdapter.getItem(i);
                            categories.setChecked(true);
                        }
                        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                            categories = listAdapter.getItem(i);
                            categories.setChecked(false);
                        }
                        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
                if (TAG == 1) {
                    TAG = 0;
                }
            }
        });

        // itemss = (mItems[]) onRetainNonConfigurationInstance();
        ArrayList<mItems> CategoryList = new ArrayList<mItems>();

        CategoryList.add(new mItems("Amusement Park"));
        CategoryList.add(new mItems("Bird Sanctuary"));
        CategoryList.add(new mItems("Wild Life"));
        CategoryList.add(new mItems("River"));
        CategoryList.add(new mItems("Hill Station"));
        CategoryList.add(new mItems("Temple"));
        CategoryList.add(new mItems("Rafting"));
        CategoryList.add(new mItems("Fishing"));
        CategoryList.add(new mItems("Hiking"));
        CategoryList.add(new mItems("Museums"));

        // Set our custom array adapter as the ListView's adapter.
        listAdapter = new SelectArralAdapter(MainActivity.context, CategoryList);
        dialog_ListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        return dialog;

    }

    private static class SelectArralAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<mItems> {
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        public SelectArralAdapter(Context context, List<mItems> planetList) {
            super(context, R.layout.dialog_row, R.id.rowTextView, planetList);
            // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each
            // time.
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Planet to display
            mItems planet = (mItems) this.getItem(position);

            // The child views in each row.
            CheckBox checkBox;
            TextView textView;

            // Create a new row view
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_row, null);

                // Find the child views.
                textView = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.rowTextView);
                checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01);
                // Optimization: Tag the row with it's child views, so we
                // don't
                // have to
                // call findViewById() later when we reuse the row.
                convertView.setTag(new SelectViewHolder(textView, checkBox));
                // If CheckBox is toggled, update the planet it is tagged
                // with.
                checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        System.out.println("uffff");
                        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                        mItems row_view = (mItems) cb.getTag();
                        row_view.setChecked(cb.isChecked());

                        TAG = 1;
                        chk_all.setChecked(false);
                        TAG = 0;

                        for (int i = 0; i < _categories.length; i++) {
                            row_view = listAdapter.getItem(i);
                            if (!row_view.isChecked()) {
                                break;
                            }

                            if (i == _categories.length - 1) {
                                TAG = 1;
                                chk_all.setChecked(true);
                                TAG = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
            // Reuse existing row view
            else {
                // Because we use a ViewHolder, we avoid having to call
                // findViewById().
                SelectViewHolder viewHolder = (SelectViewHolder) convertView
                        .getTag();
                checkBox = viewHolder.getCheckBox();
                textView = viewHolder.getTextView();
            }

            // Tag the CheckBox with the Planet it is displaying, so that we
            // can
            // access the planet in onClick() when the CheckBox is toggled.
            checkBox.setTag(planet);
            // Display planet data
            checkBox.setChecked(planet.isChecked());
            textView.setText(planet.getName());
            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I am not sure how we can include a setCustomTitle layout for the Custom Dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now i want to reference this this Check box and add a listener to the
>   Checkbox.

I'm assuming that you show the dialog using the `DialogFragment`'s `onCreateDialog` method, so in the `onCreateDialog` method you would do:

```
// inflate the layout title
View customTitle = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_title, null);
// find the CheckBox and set the listener
CheckBox ckb = (CheckBox) customTitle.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
ckb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new ...);
// set the title view on the dialog etc
```

Comment: so the content and the title will be in the same layout ?

Comment: @HarshaMV No, you would set the title with `dialogBuilder.setCustomTitle(customTitle);`

Comment: you mean to say AlertDiaglog right ? i am using final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.context); since i need to implement the check and uncheck all feature. as u suggested a few days back.

Comment: @HarshaMV I thought you used `AlertDialog`. If you use the `Dialog` class, then yes you would group the content of the dialog and the title layout from your question in a single layout file and set that as the dialog's content. You'll then look for the `CheckBox` in that inflated layout like in my answer.

Comment: i have added the code. i will have to explicitly unset the title and then build the title via layout. is there any way to access the title from the Dialog is what am confused about. hope you understand what i am trying to ask.

Comment: @HarshaMV * is there any way to access the title from the Dialog is what am confused about* Which one? From the custom title layout? If yes then simply use `findViewById` because you put it in the content(so your tile layout and your content layout will be in the same layout file which you'll set at the content view for the `Dialog` ). If you are referring to the `Dialog`'s class title I don't know why you need it(just remove the `dialog.setTitle("Categories");` line).